# jquery show/hide with div containing form and submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an html page with a few divs and a jquery which show / hides the divs. My problem is that one of the divs contain a form with a submit button. And of course each time the submit button is clicked the page reloads which also hides the div. **How do i stop it from hiding the div on submit button?**

I only want divs to hide when another href in the menu is clicked. I have php that returns errors under the form but i don't think you guys need to see that code. Thanks in advance.

**Heres the jquery:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
           $(this).show(200);   
      }
      else {
           $(this).hide(600); 
      }
 });
 }  
 </script>
```

**Here is the html:**

```
<div class="menu">
    <h1>Admin</h1>
    <a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes1');">View Products</a>
    <a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('newboxes2');">Add Products</a>
    <a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a>
</div>
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" style="display: none;">
    <p><span class="error" style="margin-left:10%;">* Required </span>
    </p>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <label>Barcode Number<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="prod_num">
        <br>

        <label>Product Name<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="prod_name">
        <br>

        <label>Description<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="prod_desc">
        <br>

        <label>Category<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <select name="prod_cat">
            <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
            <option value="Exhaust Product">Exhaust Product</option>
            <option value="Engine Product">Engine Product</option>
            <option value="Intake Product">Intake Product</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Price<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="prod_price">
        <br>

        <label>Select Image<span class="error">*</span></label>
        <input type="file" name="prod_img" style="width:auto;border:none;">
        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Product">

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: can use ajax to submit or change the display property at server if reloading with errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check whether the form has been submitted.

```
<div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2" <?php if (empty($_POST)) { ?>style="display: none;"<?php }?>>
```

You SHOULD be doing this with a class and CSS.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! and yes your right, i'll be sure you to clean it up with CSS.

Comment: Cool. Please mark my answer as Accepted. Been gypped 3 times today!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS and proper selectors to ensure when elements are visible / hidden. You've only posted inline styles, so its difficult to advise on a better CSS-based solution.  However, the following attribute on `#newboxes2` --

```
style="display: none;"
```

-- will always hide the div until your javascript changes the inline style attribute. Try removing this attribute.

More suggestions:

1. Avoid inline styles. Keep all CSS styles in a .css file. It's easier to manage in the long-run.
2. Be thoughtful of how the page works without javascript. Not all browsers have javascript enabled. (Do some reading on Progressive Enhancement)

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. As you can tell, i'm pretty new to everything. So I appreciate all the advice I can get !